# How can I toggle an img's src value between two images?

Tags: jquery, html, image, toggle, src

I want to toggle an img's src value so that the first time I click it, it changes to another image, and the second time, it reverts back to the original image.

The img is defined in HTML this way:

```
<img id="imgPostTravel" name="imgPostTravel" src="/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png" alt="post Travel image" height="275" width="350">
```

I can change the first image to the second with this jQuery:

```
$('#imgPostTravelTopRight').click(function () {
    $('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src', '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png');
});
```

I tried this to toggle the img src:

```
$('#imgPostTravelTopRight').toggle(function () {
    $('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src', '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png');
}, function () {
    $('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src', '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/2_PTE_Top_Right_Jig.png');
});
```

...but it doesn't work. I read that "toggle" was deprecated, and I tried this:

```
if $(('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src') == '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png') {
    $('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src', '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/2_PTE_Top_Right_Jig.png');
} else {
    $('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src', '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png');
}
```

...but that works even less well - in fact, it smashes "everything" all to smithereens - even code that needed to run prior to that doesn't run now...

Comment: Das klappt schon - make it an answer, and I'll mark accordingly.

Comment: I converted it into an answer as suggested. I tried to add more detail to it as well. Hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your last attempt doesn't work is because you have a syntax error:

```
if $(('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src') == '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png') {
// ^ This should be ($( instead of $((
```

Another solution is to use the [`.attr(name, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) overload:

```
$('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr("src", function(index, val) {
    return val == '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png' ?
       '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/2_PTE_Top_Right_Jig.png' :
       '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stryner had it sussed out; this works:

```
$('#imgPostTravelTopRight').click(function () {
    if ($('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src') == '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png') {
        $('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src', '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/2_PTE_Top_Right_Jig.png');
    } else {
        $('#imgPostTravelTopRight').attr('src', '/_layouts/images/TravelFormHelp/posttravelpdf.png');
    }
});
```

It may not be the most elegant solution, but it does work.

If baseball is a game of inches, programming is a game of persnickety symbols. It cannot be otherwise, but it is that nevertheless.